# Подскажите, как с помощью регулярного выражения вытащить последние 4 цифры карты?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Вот примеры возможных строк:

```
4234 2347 8084 2340
4234230842976499-номер карты
2345
*5235
```

Comment: Например, так [`\d{4}(?=[^\d]*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/r1UzEj/1)

Comment: а точно тут нужно регулярное віражение? Последние 4 символа нельзя взять?

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
texts = '4234 2347 8084 2340','4234230842976499-номер карты','2345','*5235', '123'
for text in texts:
    f=re.search(r'\d{4}(?=[^\d]*$)',text)
    if f:
        print(f[0])
```

```
2340
6499
2345
5235

[Program finished]
```